# OpenCV 2.4.3 Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic on iOS 5

Tags: ios5, opencv, ios6

I downloaded the OpenCV iOS framework [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/2.4.3/) and have it working fine with iOS 6, but on iOS 5.0, whenever I call:

```
self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:self.imageView];
```

from [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html), I get the following error message:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/8ADDFB67-97CE-4F6B-94B5-BD2548E0E6DD/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/8ADDFB67-97CE-4F6B-94B5-BD2548E0E6DD/MyApp.app/MyApp
Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

Is the latest version only for iOS 6? Is there an equivalent for iOS 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this Q&A:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/4767/build-opencv-for-ios-5/

It seems that there are issues with latest source, and they suggest that you use [the most recent pre-built framework (2.4.3)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/2.4.3/).

Having said that, I have a version I built from current source last week which is running fine on ios6.0, 5.1 and 5.0 (see github projects [here](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSquares) and [here](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSquaresSL))

But when I try the video example you pointed to with this framework, I get the same error.

So it seems like it depends on exactly which feature of openCV you are trying to use....

**update**

I have just tried 2.4.3 and get the same error. Going back one version, 2.4.2, doesn't help because `<opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>` is not present. This file declares the `CvVideoCamera` class and delegate protocol, so without it you won't get anywhere with this example. Interestingly, `cap_ios.h` is an Objective-C class declaration, unlike the rest of openCV which is C++... so this *particular* feature might well only work with ios6

**update2**

OK I managed to get it running with a recent build of openCV from the latest source.

1 / Copy these pre-build source files into your project:

opencv/modules/highgui/src/

```
cap_ios_abstract_camera.mm
cap_ios_photo_camera.mm
cap_ios_video_camera.mm
cap_ios.h
```

2 / in the three .mm files change these lines:

```
#import "opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h"
#include "precomp.hpp"
```

to:

```
#import "cap_ios.h"
// #include "precomp.hpp"
```

2 / In your viewController change

```
#import <opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>
```

to

```
#import "cap_ios.h"
```

That's about it... possibly one or two other tweaks but i think that's all it took to get it running under a deployment target of 5.1.

Comment: Hey, thanks for working on this. I followed your instructions, but I got "ld: 33 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7" in opencv2.framework/opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o). Did you use 2.4.3 or 2.4.2?

Comment: @Jason I used my build from the latest source from about a week ago. I have had great difficulties with 2.4.3. 2.4.2 is better but requires a fair few changes to your setup. If you grab one of my projects from github, those both use my recent build. But it is very straightfoward to build yourself _if_ you have an uptodate system with current CMake. I think you have already achieved this.

Comment: This works. I was facing the same problem. I did the same thing as mentioned above. I faced a problem with cap_ios_video_camera.mm stating rotateVideo property not found on object of type cap_ios_video_camera. Replaced cap_ios.h with the lateset OpenCV build cap_ios.h. That solved it.